# Intnx in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I don't understand what will be the outcome of this piece of code:

```
intnx('month', datepart(date_example), 0, 'end')
```

With date_example = '2010-05-12'
Is it '2010-05-31'?
Basically the last day of that month in that one specific year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "END" means to move to the end of the interval.  The end of a month is last day of the month.  The 0 means to move to the end of the same month.

If your date_example variable has a datetime value (number of seconds), like '12MAY2010:00:00'dt, then your code will first convert it to a date value (number of days), '12MAY2010'd , and then convert it to the end of the month of may in the year 2010, '31MAY2010'd.

If you would rather generate a datetime value for the end of the month then use the DTMONTH interval and remove the DATEPART() function.  Then the generated value will become '23:59:59't on the last of the month.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the end of the month as a datatime value (instead of a date value), use the interval `DTMONTH`.

Remember that date values are number of days from epoch, and datetime values are number of seconds.

```
data one;
  date_example = '01JUL2023:12:00:00'dt ;

  eom   = intnx('month',   datepart(date_example), 0, 'end') ;
  eomdt = intnx('dtmonth',          date_example , 0, 'end') ;

  put eom   date9. ;
  put eomdt datetime16. ;

  put eom   yymmdd10. ;
  put eomdt e8601dt24.4 ;
run;
```

Logs

```
31JUL2023
31JUL23:23:59:59
2023-07-31
2023-07-31T23:59:59.0000   (should I be surprised it's not .9999)
```